# Determine Product Key Used to Activate Windows 7

Tags: windows, windows-activation, product-key

I have an OEM version of Windows 7 running on a recently purchased Dell laptop. The laptop came with only 2 GB of memory but I'd like to upgrade it to 6 GB. To do so will require me to reinstall Windows so that I can upgrade to the 64-bit version.

I'm unable to locate the Windows 7 key on the laptop or any material included with the laptop. How can I determine the product key used to activate Windows on my machine?

**Update:** Is it the Product ID located under the following (Paste into Windows Explorer)?

> Control Panel\System and Security\System

Comment: Product ID is not the product key...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Power down the laptop and remove the battery, you should find it on the case, safely hidden away...  ;-)

Comment: Awesome! Didn't even think to look there. Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

On the command line ("cmd" in run interface in start menu) type

```
slmgr.vbs /dli
```

and wait a few seconds, a popup will appear with your serial number in it.

It will give the last five characters of your serial number if your on a OEM license, otherwise (basically for retail and volume licenses) you will get the whole serial number.

Comment: On my computer, that just gives the last five characters.

The OEM key that come with your computer might not work for the 64-bit edition.  As far as I know, only the retail keys are dual-purpose.

Comment: I believe that will only give you a partial key. I just tested with Win7 x86 and confirmed.

Comment: Worked like a charm. I was just determining which key went with which install - last 5 charecters  did just that. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There is a very nice program called Belarc Advisor which is free for personal use that will tell you many things about the state of your Windows PC including all the Microsoft activation codes in use.

Answer (score 0):

I was interested in the answer to this question myself so did a quick google.

Found the following website which may be useful.

http://pcsupport.about.com/od/productkeysactivation/ht/windows-7-key.htm

I can't verify for sure whether it works nor whether the tools page the article links to is trustworthy but it seems to answer your question.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I saw that one too. I felt the link I posted had a better explanation and was more clear on the best program to use. Funny how a simple Google search solves most questions on this site ;)

Answer (score 0):

[Magic Jellybean Keyfinder](http://www.magicaljellybean.com/keyfinder/) is the best out there.

Comment: This could be true, but considering you must pay $24.95 to recover keys for Windows 7 it is hardly a good solution considering there are free apps that will get the job done....

Comment: @Campo: Since when? Magical Jelly Bean Keyfinder shows the key (and it's copyable too) on my machine.

Comment: @Hello71: It mentions it on the Jellybean page linked to by Dan above. I was under the impressions that it got everything though...

Answer (score 0):

Being a Dell laptop it should have an OEM licensing sticker on the machine somewhere. Possibly under the battery, or just on the back of the machine.